# Google maps API V2 blank screen after installed on real device

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, emulation

When I run my app via Eclipse by using a real device (LG Optimus L3 - http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_l3_e400-4461.php) connected to my PC  The map and everything else seems OK, but after I generate the .apk file and have it installed on the same device, I have the blank screen where the map should be displayed, can see only the zoom buttons, the Google logo and my action bar. I checked similar questions here, but nothing seems to fix it.

Im using the FragmentActivity class

My manifest (Google Maps API key replaced by 'X'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="apt.login"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<permission

android:name="apt.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"

android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission
android:name="apt.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
     <meta-data

        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>

     <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Loading">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Mapa">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Splitbar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you generating a release APK? If yes, check if you are not using your debug key. Release APK should use different, signed Google Maps API Key.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: You're right. I was using a debug keystore and did not notice about it. After making some research I found this useful pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198917/android-signing-problem

Comment: And just for generating the release keystore: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Still have the blank map and when I execute command jarsigner -verbose -keystore... I have some warnings.. (any idea?): "CertPath not validated: Path doesnt chain with any of the trust anchors"

Comment: Gonna mark your answer as the right one and open a new thread for this.Thank you!!